# Symfony3 entity design for recurring dates with multiple time intervals

Tags: mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, calendar

What is best way to design recurring dates. I have `Service` entity with one-to-many relationship to `Availability` entity. So I want my service to be available on recurring dates with exceptions. For example:

- every Monday from 09:00 to 12:00 from today until 3rd March, except 20th February
- every Tuesday from 08:00 to 10:00 and 12:30 to 14:30 until 1st April
- every Thursday all day forever except 17th and 24th of March

this is what I have already:

```
 class Availability
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="time")
 */
private $startTime;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="time")
 */
private $endTime;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="day_of_week", type="integer")
 */
private $dayOfWeek;

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_list", type="array")
 */
private $dateList;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="availabilityList")
 */
private $service;
}
```

My question is what is best way to store this data? How should I change my entity? What type each of field should have?

I need to be able to search services by date, like find services available on weekday mornings, so I want my `Availability` entity to cater for this search.

Comment: I heavily recommend to use some library like the excellent https://github.com/simshaun/recurr and not trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @LBA I thought about it, but I couldn't figure out how to set multiple time intervals, like `from 08:00 to 10:00 and 12:30 to 14:30 every Monday`

Comment: see my example provided in the answer - it's possible to achieve it.

Comment: if you found your own solution would be nice to share it and provide an answer.

Answer (score 3):

We used library [Recurr](https://github.com/simshaun/recurr) for this.

Our Entity class looks basically like the following (it's stripped and not tested in this way, but it works perfectly for our case). We're only using it for recurring dates and not times, but it should'nt be an issue to use our example to continue on that.

Check it out - because I am pretty sure it's a whole lot more effort trying to build it on your own.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Recurr\Recurrence;
use Recurr\Rule;
use Recurr\Transformer\ArrayTransformer;
use Recurr\Transformer\ArrayTransformerConfig;

class Availability
{

private static $frequencyList = array(0 => 'DAILY', 1 => 'WEEKLY', 2 => 'MONTHLY', 3 => 'YEARLY');
private static $weekDays = array(0 => 'SU', 1 => 'MO', 2 => 'TU', 3 => 'WE', 4 => 'TH', 5 => 'FR', 6 => 'SA');

/**
 * @var \DateTime - indicates 'first date' of recurring timeframe
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateStart;

/**
 * @var \DateTime - indicates 'until date' of rRule
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateUntil;

/**
 * @var int - indicates 'how often' rRule applies
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $count;

/**
 * @var int - indicates 'how often' per frequency, ex. 1 means every month, 2 every other month
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true, name="freq_interval")
 */
private $interval;

/**
 * @var int - indicates 'frequency', uses self::$frequencyList
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $freq;

/**
 * @var array - indicates 'every day', uses self::$weekDays
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", nullable=true)
 */
private $byDay;

/**
 * @var array - integer indicates 'day of month', e.g. 1 is first day of month, -1 is last day
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", nullable=true)
 */
private $byMonthDay;

/**
 * @var array - integer indicates 'day of year', e.g. 1 is first day of year, -1 is last day of year
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", nullable=true)
 */
private $byYearDay;

/**
 * @var array - indicates 'every month' January is 0, December = 12
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", nullable=true)
 */
private $byMonth;

// ...getter and setter for all attributes HERE...

/**
 * @return null|\DateTime[]
 */
public function getRecurrenceCollection()
{

    if ($this->getDateEffective() !== null) {
        return null;
    }

    if ($this->getFreq() === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $result = array();

    if ($this->getFreq() !== null) {
        $rulePart[] = 'FREQ=' . self::$frequencyList[$this->getFreq()];
    }

    if ($this->getCount() !== null) {
        $rulePart[] = 'COUNT=' . $this->getCount();
    }

    if ($this->getDateUntil() !== null) {
        $rulePart[] = 'UNTIL=' . $this->getDateUntil();
    }

    if ($this->getInterval() === null) {
        $rulePart[] = 'INTERVAL=1';
    } else {
        $rulePart[] = 'INTERVAL=' . $this->getInterval();
    }
    if (count($this->getByDay()) > 0) {
        $byWeekDayArray = array();
        foreach ($this->getByDay() as $byDay) {
            $byWeekDayArray[] = self::$weekDays[$byDay];
        }

        $rulePart[] = 'BYDAY=' . implode(',', $byWeekDayArray);
    }
    if (count($this->getByMonth()) > 0) {
        $rulePart[] = 'BYMONTH=' . implode(',', $this->getByMonth());
    }
    if (count($this->getByMonthDay()) > 0) {
        $rulePart[] = 'BYMONTHDAY=' . implode(',', $this->getByMonthDay());
    }
    if (count($this->getByYearDay()) > 0) {
        $rulePart[] = 'BYYEARDAY=' . implode(',', $this->getByYearDay());
    }

    $ruleString = implode(';', $rulePart);

    $rule = new Rule($ruleString, $this->getDateStart(), null, 'UTC');

    $transformer = new ArrayTransformer();

    // enable fix for MONTHLY
    if ($this->getFreq() === 2) {
        $transformerConfig = new ArrayTransformerConfig();
        $transformerConfig->enableLastDayOfMonthFix();
        $transformer->setConfig($transformerConfig);
    }

    $elements = $transformer->transform($rule);

    /** @var Recurrence $element */
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $result[] = $element->getEnd();
    }

    return $result;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. But I still can't understand how can I set exception days and multiple time intervals during a day.

Comment: multiple time intervals are simply multiple entries here and will be returned as several entries in your 'availability list' - and did you check the library for examples on exceptions?

Comment: how to use constraints like exception dates is mentioned here in the [doc](https://github.com/simshaun/recurr#transformation-constraints)

Comment: Thank you, it seems like a good start on the entity, but please remove the getRecurrenceCollection function as it requires more from your functionality from your codebase  :)

Comment: what do you mean? i only see the TimeUtil, i will remove that. other than that what else should be required? i strongly believe the code how to a return a collection is helpful.